# Updating textarea in asp.net razor while performing tasks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using asp.net mvc 4 razor and I have a main view that has some checkboxes and a submit button. Those checkboxes indicates the tasks to be performed. User selects the tasks to be performed through the checkboxes and then he launch the process by clicking on the submit button.

Once the submit button is clicked, a the controller associated to this view is called. Within the controller I want to do the following:

1) Open another different view which has a textarea.
2) While controller is performing the tasks selected by the user, I want to update the textarea of the new view just opened (step 1). 
3) When controller finishes the tasks I want to stay in the new view just opened (step 1) to wait user action through buttons (return to the previous main view).

Note: The update of the textarea is synchronous.

For example:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult PerformTasks(ViewModel model)
{
   // model contains the values of the checkboxes. With this I know which tasks to perform.

   UpdateTextArea("Beginning tasks...");

   // ##### Do first task
   UpdateTextArea("Doing task #1...");

   // Do some stuff for task #1

   // ##### Do second task
   UpdateTextArea("Doing task #2...");

   // Do some stuff for task #2

   (...)

   // ##### Doing last task
   UpdateTextArea("Doing task #N...");

   // Do some stuff for task #N

   UpdateTextArea("Tasks completed.");

   // At the end of the process, new view just opened with contains the textarea
   // must remain to user action.
   return ¿?
}
```

The Output in the textarea for the new view just opened would be:

```
- Textarea content at the end of the process -

Beginning tasks...

Doing task #1...
Doing task #2...
Doing task #3...
...
Doing task #N...

Tasks completed.
```

How can I do this in an easy way? I do not want to use any third-party frameworks as this web app is very little.

To make it easier, the textarea could be in the same main view rather than in another different new view.

**FIRST ATTEMPT** (AminSaghi solution):

The main view has the following aspect now (simplified to 2 tasks):
(see at the end my issues when trying to implement it)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(
     "PerformTasks", "Tests", FormMethod.Post,
     htmlAttributes: new { id = "frm" }))
{ 
   (...)
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.task01)<span>Task 1</span><br />
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.task02)<span>Task 2</span><br />
   (...)
       <input type="submit" value="Do Tasks" />
       <div id="divStatus">
       </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

// First ajax script
$("#frm").submit(function (event) {
    $("#frm").validate();
    if ($("#frm").valid()) {
       $.ajax({
                url: "/Tests/PerformTasks/",
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#frm").serialize(),
                success: function() {            
                          perFormTask1();
                },
                beforeSend: function() { 
                     $("#divStatus").append('<br/>Begginig tasks...<br/>'); 
                }           
       });
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});

// second ajax script
function performTask1() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Tests/Task1/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#frm").serialize(),
    success: function() { 
        $("#divStatus").append('Task1 completed.<br/>');           
        perFormTask2();
    },
    beforeSend: function() { 
        $("#divStatus").append('<br/>Begginig task 1...<br/>'); 
    }            
  });
};

function performTask2() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Tests/Task2/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#frm").serialize(),
    success: function() { 
        $("#divStatus").append('Task2 completed.<br/>');
    },
    beforeSend: function() { 
        $("#divStatus").append('<br/>Begginig task 2...<br/>'); 
    }            
  });
};

</script>
```

Controller (TestsController.cs under \Controllers):

```
public class TestsController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult PerformTasks(ViewModel model)
  {
      // Nothing to do here, tasks are done individually in the methods below.
      // To stay in the same page after submit button is clicked
      return Redirect(this.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Task1(ViewModel model)
  {
     // Task 1 should be done if checkbox in the main view is checked, otherwise not.
     bool doTask1 = model.task01;
     if (doTask1 )
     {
       // Do some stuff
     }         

     // To stay in the same page after submit button is clicked
     return Redirect(this.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Task2(ViewModel model)
  {
    // Task 2 should be done if checkbox in the main view is checked, otherwise not.
    bool doTask2 = model.task02;
    if (doTask2)
    {
       // Do some stuff
    }

    // To stay in the same page after submit button is clicked
    return Redirect(this.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath);
  }
}
```

The model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public bool task01{ get; set; }
    public bool task02{ get; set; }
}
```

Things I do not understand and I do not kwnow how to do:

```
1.- Once submit button is clicked, how to launch first ajax script in order to start the tasks sequence?
2.- Action PerformTasks as I understand should be leave empty, only return to the same page line should be put, am I right, because it
only launches the others in the ajax script.
3.- What is #frm in the ajax script? should i replace with something?
4.-I think for the last task, in this case task 2, is not necessary to do another ajax script as this is the last, Am I right?
5.-If some task fails, for example task 1, below tasks should be done, in this case task 2. How to do this?
6.-For each task I should pass some data, the status of all checkboxes and the within each action in the controller check if
this task has been checked to be done. If so, task is performed, if
not, task is not performed. How to pass this data to tasks, 1 and 2?
through data element in ajax?
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a 3rd party tool like signalr, then I would recommend that you split your controller into the several tasks and then use a jquery get/post to set each of the tasks in turn, when the task returns, update the textarea with the next phase to be undertaken

Comment: Can SignalR be installed on visual studio express 2010?

Comment: its a nuget package, so yeah, i would have thought so

Comment: sorry, ok, i have installed it successfully but it seems a lot complicated for a newbie in asp.net programming.... Can I use and updatepanel ajax control instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to brick your action method into separate task:

```
public ActionResult PerformTasks(ViewModel model)
{
    //
}

public ActionResult Task1(string param1, string param2, ...)
{
    //
}

public ActionResult Task2((string param1, string param2, ...)
{
    //
}

// and so on...
```

Then, in your view, put each of them into the ajax `success` option of its previous task ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/PerformTasks/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: $("#frm").serialize(),
    success: function() {            
        perFormTask1();
    },
    beforeSend: function() { 
        $("#divStatus").append('<br/>Begginig tasks...<br/>'); 
    }            
});
```

And function `performTask1` can be like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/Task1/",
    type: 'POST',
    data: ... // here or by query string,
    success: function() { 
        $("#divStatus").append('Task1 completed.<br/>');           
        perFormTask2();
    },
    beforeSend: function() { 
        $("#divStatus").append('<br/>Begginig task 1...<br/>'); 
    }            
});
```

And so on for other tasks...

So, the semi-complete how-to is like the following:

1) Change your `Html.BeginForm()` like this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(
    "action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, 
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "frm"})) 
{
    // in fact, in our situation, 
    // there is no matter to put correct values in action and controller parameters 
    // because we'll override them and do our job through ajax...
}
```

2) Add the following script into your view:

```
<script>
    $("#frm").submit(function (event) {
        $("#frm").validate();
        if ($("#frm").valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Controller/PerformTasks/",
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#frm").serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    perFormTask1();
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#divStatus").append('<br/>Begginig tasks...<br/>');
                }
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        }                
    });

    function performTask1() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Controller/Task1?param1=data1&param2=data2 ...",
            type: 'POST',            
            success: function() { 
                $("#divStatus").append('Task1 completed.<br/>');           
                perFormTask2();
            },
            beforeSend: function() { 
                $("#divStatus").append('<br/>Begginig task 1...<br/>'); 
            }            
        });
    }

    // and also for other task, add similar performTask functions...
</script>
```

Comment: This is just what I was searching for :))) but i am trying to make it work and due to my inexperience in web application programming i have some problems: what is #divstatus? I guess the name of my textarea:   <textarea rows="100" cols="10" id="testsProgress" style="resize: none;">
   </textarea>. And #form? Also you say I have to put $.ajax blocks in my view within <script type="text/javascript"> </script>? And when user click on submit button how to call first ajax script? my button is within @using (Html.BeginForm ... block. sorry by my ignorance.

Comment: @user1624552 - There is no shame or sorry in learning... `divStatus` is the id of the container you'll use to show tasks status messages. I suggest you to create it with <div> instead of <textarea> becuase div is much flexible and easier to use.

Comment: I set your answer as my accepted one. I have some problems trying to do what you said me. Better if I post another thread with these new issues. I post here the link later.

Comment: @user1624552 - No... just let me to update my answer and put a full code at the end for you...

Comment: Ok. so I am going to put here at the end.

Comment: I have implemented your solution, main PerformTasks method is called but when it finish, PerformTask1 is not executed. I have left PerformTasks in the controller as empty as nothing has to be done here. How to pass my ViewModel to the tasks in controller? in script I put url: "/Tests/Task1?model=ViewModel"

Comment: @user1624552 - Note that sending values to `PerformTasks` is different from `Task` methods... They also differ in their url type in script... and remember to put `[HttpPost]` on all action methods...

Comment: @user1624552 - If you want to send the model to all tasks, change their urls like the url of `PerformTasks` in the script and add the `data:` option to their ajax code. You also need to change parameters of action methods to `ViewModel model` just like the PerformTasks action method.

Comment: Hi again, I have changed the url to all the tasks in ajax script to be the same as PerformTasks, for example, for task 1, url: "/Controller/Task1/" and the I have added the data: option to each ajax script as well like: data: $("#frm").serialize(). Also [HttpPost] attribute added on all action methods: PerformTasks, Task1 and Task2. Doing so PerformTasks action in the controller gets executed (I have check by putting a breakpoint) but after this action finishes, the next is not called, I mean, in this case, action Task1 in controller (I have put a breakpoint and never reaches there).Any idea?

Comment: I forgot to say that I have changed the parameters for action methods in the controller to be the same ViewModel model as in the PerformTasks action but it continues without working, first call to PerformTasks action is done in the controller but after that next action, Task1 is not called.

Comment: @user1624552 - change `success:` option to `complete:` in all of them

Comment: I have updated the post, see section "First attempt". When I run below error appears: "Error in runtime Javascript: '$' is not defined"  in the script line:  $("#frm").submit(function (event) Also I have changed all success: option to complete:

Comment: Below error $ not defined solved by changing <script> to <script  src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> but continues happening the same, action PerformTasks is executed on controller but then next action is not reached. I wonder if in the PerformTasks action in the controller i have to put something to indicate task has been completed, is it necessary? now is empty and only the line return exists there.

Comment: @user1624552 - Just one more think I can suggest...! change `ActionResult` from all methods to `JsonResult`. Also change the `return Redirect(...)` to `return Json("")`...

Comment: The same result... :( I think it is not reaching the task2 because line of first script  url: "/Tests/PerformTasks/" is not being executed because if I put some url does not exists it does not crash, PerformTasks is reached as a result of this line:@using (Html.BeginForm(
    "PerformDiagnostic", "Tests", FormMethod.Post,
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "frm" }))

Comment: The problem is the one I have described in my previous comment: First script is not being executed. so no complete event is raised and no action Task 2 is executed...

Comment: I think it is better to open another thread as the solution you have posted is totally valid despite this little error. So I am going to open another post to comment this issue.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18898311/javascript-event-handler-is-not-intercepting-the-form-submission

Comment: Could be the problem that I am not putting the script block in the correct place within the page? where script block should be put?